uWSGI: trying to figure out why my application goes frequently timeout
I'm using uWSGI into a Docker container to serve a Django application which is encountering serious timeouts problems almost once per day.
For this reason, I am debugging my uWSGI settings, expecially the cheaper settings.
Today I had timeouts errors at about 06:30 UTC time, and these are the uWSGI logs in the meantime:
2024-06-12 06:03:02 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:03:03 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:03:04 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:03:05 - [busyness] backlog was non-zero for 60 second(s), spawning new worker(s)
2024-06-12 06:03:05 - [busyness] 18 requests in listen queue but we are already started maximum number of workers (8)
2024-06-12 06:03:06 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:03:07 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:03:08 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
[...]
2024-06-12 06:04:14 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:04:15 - [busyness] backlog was non-zero for 69 second(s), spawning new worker(s)
2024-06-12 06:04:15 - [busyness] 51 requests in listen queue but we are already started maximum number of workers (8)
2024-06-12 06:04:16 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
[...]
2024-06-12 06:05:14 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:05:15 - [busyness] backlog was non-zero for 60 second(s), spawning new worker(s)
2024-06-12 06:05:15 - [busyness] 83 requests in listen queue but we are already started maximum number of workers (8)
2024-06-12 06:05:16 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
[...]
2024-06-12 06:05:53 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:05:54 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket ":8000" (fd: 8) full !!! (100/100) ***
2024-06-12 06:05:54 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:05:55 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket ":8000" (fd: 8) full !!! (101/100) ***
2024-06-12 06:05:55 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:05:56 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket ":8000" (fd: 8) full !!! (101/100) ***
2024-06-12 06:05:56 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:05:57 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket ":8000" (fd: 8) full !!! (101/100) ***
2024-06-12 06:05:57 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:05:58 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket ":8000" (fd: 8) full !!! (101/100) ***
2024-06-12 06:05:58 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:05:59 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket ":8000" (fd: 8) full !!! (101/100) ***
2024-06-12 06:05:59 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
[...]
2024-06-12 06:06:23 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket ":8000" (fd: 8) full !!! (101/100) ***
2024-06-12 06:06:23 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:06:24 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket ":8000" (fd: 8) full !!! (101/100) ***
2024-06-12 06:06:24 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:06:25 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket ":8000" (fd: 8) full !!! (101/100) ***
2024-06-12 06:06:25 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:06:26 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 100% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:06:27 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 96% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
[...]
2024-06-12 06:10:06 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 71% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:11:04 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 80% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:12:54 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 0%, cheap one of 8 running workers
2024-06-12 06:12:55 - worker 8 killed successfully (pid: 5306)
2024-06-12 06:12:55 - uWSGI worker 8 cheaped.
2024-06-12 06:13:27 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 0%, cheap one of 7 running workers
2024-06-12 06:13:36 - worker 4 killed successfully (pid: 5310)
2024-06-12 06:13:36 - uWSGI worker 4 cheaped.
2024-06-12 06:13:59 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 0%, cheap one of 6 running workers
2024-06-12 06:14:06 - worker 1 killed successfully (pid: 5314)
2024-06-12 06:14:06 - uWSGI worker 1 cheaped.
2024-06-12 06:14:42 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 78%, will spawn 1 new worker(s)
2024-06-12 06:14:42 - Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 5347)
2024-06-12 06:14:46 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 82%, will spawn 1 new worker(s)
2024-06-12 06:14:46 - Respawned uWSGI worker 4 (new pid: 5351)
2024-06-12 06:15:03 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 76%, will spawn 1 new worker(s)
2024-06-12 06:15:03 - Respawned uWSGI worker 8 (new pid: 5355)
2024-06-12 06:15:04 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 89% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:15:06 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 78% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)
2024-06-12 06:15:40 - [busyness] 1s average busyness is at 76% but we already started maximum number of workers available with current limits (8)

This is my uWSGI configuration:
[uwsgi]
strict = true
master = true
enable-threads = true
vacuum = true
single-interpreter = true
die-on-term = true
need-app = true
lazy-apps = false
no-defer-accept = true
py-call-osafterfork = true
thunder-lock = true

# Avoid errors on aborted client connections
ignore-sigpipe = true
ignore-write-errors = true
disable-write-exception = true

disable-logging = true
log-5xx = true
log-date = %%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%M:%%S
logformat-strftime

log-format = [pid: %(pid)|app: -|req: -/-] %(addr) (%(user)) {%(vars) vars in %(pktsize) bytes} [%(ctime)] %(method) %(uri) => generated %(rsize) bytes in %(msecs) msecs (%(proto) %(status)) %(headers) headers in %(hsize) bytes (%(switches) switches on core %(core))
logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi/logger.log
req-logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi/req-logger.log

harakiri = 21600

max-requests = 1000
max-worker-lifetime = 3600
reload-on-rss = 2048
worker-reload-mercy = 60

processes = 8

cheaper-algo = busyness
cheaper = 2
cheaper-initial = 4
cheaper-overload = 1
cheaper-step = 1

cheaper-busyness-multiplier = 30
cheaper-busyness-min = 20
cheaper-busyness-max = 70
cheaper-busyness-backlog-alert = 64
cheaper-busyness-backlog-step = 2

http-socket = :8000

http-timeout = 600
http-connect-timeout = 600
http-enable-proxy-protocol = 1
http-auto-chunked = true
http-keepalive = 1
add-header = Connection: Keep-Alive

chdir = .
wsgi-file = /app/wsgi.py

gid = app
uid = app

pidfile = /tmp/uwsgi.pid

route = ^/info* donotlog:

stats = :1785
stats-http = true

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong into my uWSGI settings, expecially into cheaper configuration, what happened when above logs were printed and what I could to to avoid this to happen again.
I'm using the busyness cheaper algorithm, and I searched a lot about it.
I see that is should be the most versatile option, but it seems to also be the most complex to be optimised.
Is it true?
Should I move to another simpler algorithm like spare?
Do you have any idea about what is happening?
